# Mapping an address to a balance with keeping history of transactions

Tags: solidity, contract-development, addresses, events, mapping

I have a balance as follows such that after changing its value, I want to keep the history of previous transactions, for example, for the first time, value of `Energy_Balance` is `5` and for the second time `2` units will be added to `Energy_Balance` such that the total value will be `7`. Now I want to keep the **history of all transactions** such that we would be able to know what was the **first value** (i.e. `5`) and what was the **second transaction value** (i.e. `2`). If I have to define an `event` for this, how to **define** it and how to **invoke event** ?

```
mapping(address => uint256) Energy_Balance
```

In case of using an array as proposed by user **Eli Drion**, as follows:

```
mapping (address => uint[]) Energy_Balance
```

How can I set the new value of Energy_Balance ? For example,

```
First Transaction: balances[owner][0] = balances[owner][0] + value; 
Second Transaction: balances[owner][1] = balances[owner][1] + value;
```

**is correct ?**

Comment: use events in your contract and filter in your app https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethfilter

Answer (score 2):

> Now I want to keep the history of all transactions

You will need to use an array then, because the order matters here. If you don't need more informations about the user, you don't need to use a struct then, you can directly do like that.

```
mapping (address => uint[]) txs_history;
```

> If I have to define an event for this, how to define it and how to invoke event ?

**Defining an event**

`event MyEvent(address _sender, uint _amount);`

**Invoking an event**

```
function myFunction(uint _amount) {
    //we do alot of things here
    MyEvent(msg.sender, _amount);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean one of your proposed approaches is enough or i have to use both "array" and "event" ? thanks

Comment: If you use a UI (website) interacting with the contract, you want to use events, otherwise the website doesn't know what happens.

Comment: So it means one of approaches is enough ? ex. array or event ? Thanks

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. If you have a website, you will have to use events too eventually.

Comment: Thanks again. And do you agree with what I edited in my question ? Is it correct ?

Comment: I don't get your last two lines. It's for the history of txs, not to calculate the balance. Plus, you might want to use signed integers too, because tokens can get in but get out too

Comment: And do you agree with what i did for calculate new balance ? Is it correct ? Also I do not understand what signed integers means ? Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's correct. For signed and unsigned integers, I will let you find online what it means. :)

Comment: Thank you :) meanwhile, for "balances[owner][counter] = balances[owner][counter] + value" i think that i need to define a "static uint counter" such that "counter" keeps its last value. Is not it ? If so, how to define it in solidity ?  static uint counter = 0 is correct ?